# Blank PDF is generated is number of pages exceeds 17

Tags: pdf-generation, tcpdf

I get a blank page when I generate a PDF using tcpdf in some cases. If the number of pages is less than 17 it will generate correctly the file. If it's greater a blank pdf page will be generated. This is my code

```
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(0,5,0,0);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(FALSE);
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4');
$pdf->SetFont('arialuni','',10);
$pdf->writeHTML($Content, true, 0, true, true);
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `allow maximum execution` time for PHP script.

Set the maximum execution time in your **PHP.ini**. [Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

If it doesn't work, add `set_time_limit(0);` on top of your PHP Script.